# jQuery method .change alternatives?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

I am trying to build a form of four selects that depend on each other, i.e. they change their drop-down indexes according to each other. The problem is, when I use .change() it works perfectly when I change the value of the selector manually. What I want is for all the selectors to change automatically when I change the first one, in the sense that the third select senses the change of the second one that changed automatically when I chose the first one.
I hope it's clear what I want.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#google").change(function() {
      var Sid = $("#google").val();
      console.log(Sid);
      $.ajax({
        url: '',
        method: 'post',
        data: 'Sid=' + Sid
      }).done(function(bings) {
        console.log(bings);
        bings = JSON.parse(bings);
        $('#bing').empty();
        bings.forEach(function(bing) {
          console.log(bing);
          $('#bing').append('<option>' + bing.bingkey + '</option>')
          $("#bing").val($("#bing option:first").val());
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: *"I hope it's clear what I want"* .... not really. Provide a [mcve]